# Angular, read and stringify a local SQL script file

Tags: angular, nativescript

The context is as follows:

- I've created a basic **nativescript/angular** app. With an embedded **SQLite** database.
- I use **nativescript-sqlite** plugin

What I would like to achieve: by placing the initialization sql script in the project's directory structure (somewhere), I want to have a service initializing the database (if not present)

Where I am at right now:

- I've placed the "db.sql" init script file containing the following (but it could be any sql script) at the "app" directory level in the project:

```js
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "individual" (
    "id"    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "sex"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "surname"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "suname_birth"  TEXT,
    "is_central"    NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "id_relationship_parents"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("id_relationship_parents") REFERENCES "individual"("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "individual_birth_infos" (
    "id_individual" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "city_birth_place"  TEXT,
    "country_birth_place"   TEXT,
    "date_birth"    TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY("id_individual") REFERENCES "individual"("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "individual_death_infos" (
    "id_individual" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "city_death_place"  TEXT,
    "country_death_place"   TEXT,
    "date_death"    TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY("id_individual") REFERENCES "individual"("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "relationship" (
    "id"    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "id_man"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "id_woman"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "date_start"    TEXT,
    "date_end"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK__man_individual_relationship" FOREIGN KEY("id_man") REFERENCES "individual"("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK__woman_individual_relationship" FOREIGN KEY("id_woman") REFERENCES "individual"("id")
);
COMMIT;
```

- I've built the service as follows:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as AppConstants from "../../app-constants";

const Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");

// try to read file here
import * as InitializationScriptFileContent from "../../db.sql";

@Injectable()
export class SqliteHelperService {
    private initializationScript: any;
    private db: any;

    public constructor() {
        this.initializationScript = InitializationScriptFileContent; // <- stringify somewhere here
        
        this.initDataBaseIfNotExists(this.initializationScript);
    }

    public getDatabase() {
        return this.db;
    }

    public initDataBaseIfNotExists(creationScript: string) {
        if (!Sqlite.exists(AppConstants.SQLITE_DB_NAME_DEFAULT)) {
            Sqlite.copyDatabase(AppConstants.SQLITE_DB_NAME_DEFAULT);
        }
        new Sqlite(AppConstants.SQLITE_DB_NAME_DEFAULT).then(
            (db) => {
                db.execSQL(creationScript).then(
                    (id) => {
                        this.db = db;
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        console.log("CREATE TABLE ERROR", error);
                    }
                );
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("OPEN DB ERROR", error);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

- I've added a "sql-typings.d.ts" to the root of the project as follows:

```js
declare module "*.sql" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

When I run the build, I receive the following error:

`ERROR in ./src/app/db.sql 1:6 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders`

If anyone has any idea how to read/parse/stringify a ".sql" file, would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

**P.S:** I use angular v.13

Comment: No experience with sqllite, however, I would suspect that your ‘sql’ file should be a string. I guess you can simply wrap the entire thing in export const sql = ‘’. Import and use InitializationScriptFileContent.sql ?

Comment: @MikeOne thanks for your suggestion. The problem I see with it is having to format the whole sql by hand before. The sql (as in my example) is full of double quotes (sometimes single quotes and special characters too)